# Duplicate index and correct creation/usage of index

Tags: mysql

I think we do have duplicate indexes. Could you please help me with any tool or query to identify the duplicate indexes? Below are the indexes available on one of my major tables and I found some performance issues with a few of the queries. Please suggest any indexes which can be dropped or modified.

```
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `TLC` (`tlc_unique_check`),
KEY `idx_uniqueId` (`uniqueId`),
KEY `idx_jobs_feed_state_city` (`state`,`city`),
KEY `idx_jobs_feed_guid` (`guid`),
KEY `idx_jobstatus_is_deleted_jobtitle` (`job_status`,`is_deleted`,`jobtitle`),
KEY `Idx_delfgfjpost` (`deleted_from_gfj`,`posted_to_gfj`),
KEY `idx_is_updated` (`is_updated`),
KEY `idx_company_logo` (`company`,`custom_logo`),
KEY `idx_is_deleted_locExpand` (`is_deleted`,`locExpand`),
KEY `idx_locexpand_jobid` (`locExpand`,`clientJobId`)
```

Comment: why do you think you have duplicate indexes?  none of those indexes would do in place of another one.  and only you can know if you have queries that need any one of those indexes.

Comment: The indices may be considered as duplicates when the expression of one index is a prefix of the expression of another index. But even in this case the presence of such "duplicates" may make sense.

Comment: I think the correct question is, do you have indexes that are not (really) being used. That cannot be determined just by looking at the indexes, because that depends on what queries you're running. And we don't even know what the fields are -- like `is_updated`. Sounds like boolean field, and then indexing might not be useful -- but depending on use case, it could be also very useful.

Comment: What's the datatype of `tlc_unique_check`?  If it is  a UUID, I will point out various issues in that direction.  What is `uniqueId` if it is not declared `UNIQUE`?

Comment: Really, we must see the queries (Select/Update/Delete) to see what indexes are _needed_.  Then you can get rid of the rest.

Comment: tlc_unique_check is varchar(50)

Answer (score 1):

(I will assume that the word "duplicate" was not the real intent of your Question.  Instead, the title should have been "How to find an optimal set of indexes".)

The Percona toolkit has a pretty good way to discover which indexes are used, but with two flaws:

- It can easily miss a rarely-used, but vital index.
- It can't advise on redundant or inadequate indexes.

Also...

- Slow:  UUIDs are bad if the table is huge -- caching is virtually useless with them.
- May be bad:  Rarely does a table need more than one Unique index; I see two.  That is a *possible* red flag.
- May be unused:  Usually a "flag" (eg, `is_updated`?) is useless to be indexed by itself.  On the other hand, composite indexes including such may be useful (eg, (`is_deleted`,`locExpand`))
- Good:  No index that is the prefix of another.

But, the best approach is to see the queries and [*deduce the optimal indexes from the queries*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)